# Save Datagridview if it is Checked by CheckboxColumn

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hello Everyone Good Afternoon,

I have an Object in a form and they are `Datagridview1` and a Save `Button` the `Datagridview1` will populate data from my Database on `Form_Load` and the Data will show with a Corresponding Checkbox. Like the Image below

[image]

and If you here is the code for that

```
 Private Sub loadtech()
        Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=operations;userid=root;password=admin1950;Convert Zero Datetime=True")
        Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select TechName from technicians order by Category ASC", con1)
        Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
        con1.Open()
        adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
        adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        con1.Close()

        With DataGridView1
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Technician / Electrician"
        End With
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Width = 150
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Tag"
        checkBoxColumn.Width = 30
        checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn)
    End Sub
```

and my Question is how can I save the Checked Row in Database? Lets say I checked all of it so the Rows will be saved in Database. (Regardless of How many I Checked)

Here is my code but its not working. :(

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=operations;userid=root;password=admin1950;Convert Zero Datetime=True")
        conn.Open()

        Dim comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand()
        comm.Connection = conn


        Dim name As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count
            name = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value


            comm.CommandText = "insert into assignments(ElecAssigned) values('" & name & "')"
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

TYSM For future help

Comment: You need to make `MySqlDataAdapter` a class variable so you can use it to create a `InsertCommand` based on the `SelectCommand`. You'll have to add parameters too. Then you would call `DataAdapter.Update` method and `DataTable.AcceptChanges` method. Maybe I'll make an answer.

Comment: Actually, you would need `UpdateCommand` I think. When you call `DataAdapter.Update(yourDataTable.Changes)` it executes your `UpdateCommand` for every changed row. The `DataTable.AcceptChanges` tells the DataTable you have dealt with the changes so it can start over keeping track of changes.

Comment: Sir I dont know how to do it, Please help me Sir.

Comment: ok, let me see if I can come up with something without modifying your structure too much.

Comment: Thank You so so Much Sir, I think it has something to do with Command of  `If Else` inside `For Each`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your loop is slightly incorrect. Try using this loop and see if that fixes your issue. The issue,  you didn't use the `i` variable. It should be placed in `Row(i)` and you were looping from 0 to Count when it should be 0 to Count - 1

```
Dim name As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
           If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then
            name = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value


            comm.CommandText = "insert into assignments(ElecAssigned) values('" & name & "')"
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
           End If
        Next
```

Comment: Wait Sir I will try it now :)

Comment: sorry, forgot the `i` increment. Copy the loop again.

Comment: Sir I only checked one row in the Datagridview but all of them was saved. :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm really tired. Don't use with `i+=1` it should be Step 1 like it is now.

Comment: Wait sir Let me try it again

Comment: Sir still the same. :( I only checked one row in the Datagridview but all of them was saved. :( –

Comment: Ok try the one with the IF statement. Sorry. I am trying to do this through a TV and tired.

Comment: The one with the IF should only insert when item is checked.

Comment: Its not saving Sir. :(

Comment: Really? In my datagrid checkboxes 1 is true and 0 is false. Try it now with True instead of 1

Comment: Should be calling by header name though

Comment: I change the code to something like this `name = Me.DataGridView1.Rows("Technician / Electrician").Cells(1).Value` but its still not working. :(

Comment: Did you try this one with `If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True`

Comment: The code worked Sir but when  i checked a data the row will save but when i checked another one the past data still saves.

Comment: Sir all I can say is TYSM its already done. I will check now your answer. :) CHEERS

Comment: Yeah this loops through everything and if it's checked it inserts into DB. It does not check if something is already in the DB.